# Differ between numbers and letters in binary

Tags: binary, numbers, bit

in binary how do you differ between numbers and letters? I believe that positive numbers begin with 0000 and negative with 1000, then add the next 4 digits so -5 would be 1000 0101.

I know capital/lowercase letters start with 0100 and 0110 so just wondering if I was right about the number thing.

Also, if you could can tell me how to do decimals or special symbols that would be great, 
Thanks - Jon

Answer (score 0):

Binary is just a representation of a value. It's true that for signed values, if MSB is 1 the value is negative and if the MSB is 0 the value is positive. However the second part of your statement is not correct. `1000 0101` is not -5, it's actually -123. To represent -5 you take the value 5, which is `0000 0101`, invert all bits, and add one, giving you `1111 1011`. This is called [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Your next statement

> I know capital/lowercase letters start with 0100 and 0110

May not necessarily be true. It depends on the character encoding. In ASCII, for example, uppercase Latin letters A-Z range from 65 to 90, which can be represented in binary as `0100 0001` through `0101 1010`, and the lowercase letters a-z are from 97 to 122, which is represented in binary as `0110 0001` through `0111 1010`.

> Also, if you could can tell me how to do decimals or special symbols that would be great

Again, depends on the encoding. If we're talking about ASCII, a decimal is 46, which in binary is `0010 1110`.

Here's a table with all 8-bit ASCII characters: http://ascii-code.com/

If you want other characters beyond ASCII, you'll need to look into [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).